# VPN connection failure with Virgin Media

Tags: vpn

How do I VPN to my workplace after setting up Virgin Media? It doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Paraphrasing: [user 'iwebsol' in the Virgin Media support forum](http://community.virginmedia.com/t5/Internet-Security/Virgin-Media-Firewall-and-VPN-access-problems/td-p/1432320)**

> Vigin Media upgraded broadband connection in August 2012. Please
>   follow these steps to unblock VPN connection:
>
> 1. Type 192.168.0.1 in Your Web-browser (e.g. Google Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer).
> 2. Enter Username/Password (If you have never seen this try: "admin" as username and "changeme" as password, or phone Virgin Media if it
>      still does not work).
> 3. Goto Advanced Settings (at the bottom of the page).
> 4. Goto (Security) "Port Forwarding".
> 5. Select "PPTP(TCP:1723)" in Service, replace the .0 with a .3 in the IP Address field. and Click "Add Rule" followed by Apply.
> 6. Goto (Security) "Firewall".
> 7. Uncheck all boxes except "PPTP Pass-Through".
> 8. Click Apply.
> 9. Now try to log-in to the VPN again, with your usual user/password combination. It should work!
>
> Variations to the above instructions if they did not work:
>
> If step 1. did not work then open your terminal/cmd and type
>   "ipconfig" then look for an ip address to use instead of "192.168.0.1"
>   ... trial and error with the ip addresses that are listed in the
>   terminal/cmd.
>
> After entering this into your browser you should see a page looking
>   like:
>
> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>
> If step 5. did not work, it may be because it is asking you for an ip
>   address again. Open your terminal/cmd and type "ipconfig" then look
>   for an ip address to use where it asks for one. If it does not work,
>   then use another ip adress shown in the terminal/cmd - one of them
>   will work!

Comment: I was able to fix my VPN connection problems just by enabling the "PPTP Pass-Through" checkbox. The port forwarding part may be unnecessary.